# Is not sensing "like" something

Tags: qualia, sentience

is not sensing e.g. a colour like something?
i'm slightly colour blind, and i can assure you that i "see" all colours. of course i'm seeing something people will full colour vision can see. 
but if the colour of some **particular** red patch is like something, and that seeing a grey patch is too, then is that not enough to think that not seeing its redness is too?
the reply could read that people with colour vision have an identical qualitative experience as the colour blind, but with a little bit more, and so being colour blind is not like anything at all - except having vision, seeing shape and form.
but it does seem to me that darkness is like something, in addition to the absence of light, and so why not greyscale or whatever?

we can maybe imagine someone who was never able to blink

Answer (score 1):

1. You can only see all the colors that you can see.
2. If you are color blind (like me) you cannot see all the colors that people who are not color blind can see; just as you cannot see the ultra violet light that some birds and insects can see, and there is nothing it is like for you to NOT see the ultra violet light that some birds and insects can see.
3. Why do you think that darkness is the same as not having the vision sense at all?

Comment: i didn't quite say that - i said that darkness is like something, like not seeing a colour.
???

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the reply of "nir", above.  It may also be worth considering the following :

You "see" what everyone else sees in the sense the all of the same information enters your eye.  By "information" I mean all of the same electro-magnetic radiation, including optical light, enters your eye.

However, when your body converts this informational data into electrical data and fires it down your optic nerve into your brain, then your brain will certainly interpret that information differently from other observers - perhaps in very subtle ways, but differently nonetheless.

Comment: i am not sure that people who lack e.g. red colour vision lack the "visual sense of red", in any way other than not seeing reds

Comment: @user3293056 I agree with you.  It is just that any individual's brain interprets the data "red" in a manner differently from everyone else.

Comment: @NickR, in your sense of seeing, does a house see the sky because light from the sky enters the house through the open window?

Comment: @nir I must confess to being entirely perplexed by your comment.  My answer is no, a house does not have any of the necessary attributes - i.e., a brain, optic nerve, etc...

Comment: @NickR, hmm, you are right, sorry. Nevertheless, for color blind people information is most commonly already lost at the retina because of spectral sensitivity problems with the color receptors.

Comment: @nir That's a good point. Are you saying that the retina prevents the data "red" from being encoded electronically before being transmitted to the brain.  In this case, apparently the brain assigns a colour to the image.  That colour is what that individual calls "red" and the brain appears to respond to the absence of "red" colour data consistently over time.  Similarily, suppose that damage to the thalamus prevents colour data from being distributed correctly. Then the corrupted data processing would still be "red" for that individual.

Comment: There are various forms of color blindness; most commonly the green receptors spectral sensitivity is shifted too close to that of the red receptors, and the result is that the green and red receptors signal the "same" information, and as result the brain can distinguish between fewer colors. An analogy to what it is like is that if you can look at a number between 0 and 10 and say with confidence 2.3 or 6.7, I will look at it and may only tell if it is 2 or 7, and will often confuse a 6 with a 9.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16600/discussion-between-nick-r-and-nir).